# What do I do with label_join in promql?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I want to collect CPU usage for deployment distributed by namespace in Kubernets.

Now I am collecting as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMzRc.png)

But there are several deployment in namespace.

I want to collect cpu usage in the name of deployment, but I can't because the query of promql is difficult.

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Please add the query you're using.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira

Thanks for the comment.

The query I use is as follows.


sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~".+", namespace!="kuberhealthy", container!~"POD"}[5m]) and on (namespace)
(count(kube_pod_info{created_by_kind="ReplicaSet",kubernetes_name="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics"}) by (namespace))) by (namespace)

Comment: Why you don't change "by (namespace)" to "by (name)" or another label as you like?